# How to get the support_ values from RFE pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, rfe

I created a Pipeline with `RFE` and `RandomForestClassifer` in it and then applied `RandomizedSearchCV` to find the best hyperparameter values for both. This is what my code looks like -

```
from sklearn.esemble_learning import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

steps = [
         ("rfe", RFE(estimator = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 42))),
         ("est", RandomForestClassifier())
]
rf_clf_pl = Pipeline(steps = steps)

params = {
    "rfe__n_features_to_select" : range(2, smote_X_train.shape[1] + 1),
    "est__random_state" : np.linspace(0, 42, 5).astype(int),
    "est__n_estimators" : range(50, 201, 10),
    "est__max_depth" : [None] + list(range(5, max_depth, 3)),
    "est__max_leaf_nodes" : [None] + list(range(100, max_leaf_nodes, 20))
}

rs = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf_clf_pl, cv = 4, param_distributions = params, n_jobs = -1, n_iter = 100, random_state = 42)
rs.fit(smote_X_train, smote_y_train)
```

I tried using the code below but got an error -

```
rf_clf_pl.named_steps["rfe"].support_
```

Error -

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-c73290f0e090> in <module>()
----> 1 rf_clf_pl.named_steps["rfe"].support_

AttributeError: 'RFE' object has no attribute 'support_'
```

How can I get the name of the retained features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the retained features of the *best estimator* as follows:

```
rs.best_estimator_.named_steps['rfe'].support_
```

Namely, you should access the `best_estimator_` attribute of the `RandomizedSearchCV` fitted instance (i.e. the pipeline re-fitted with the best found hyperparameters thanks to the default parameter `refit=True` of `RandomizedSearchCV`).

The way you were trying to access attribute `support_` from the pipeline instance does not work because you've not explicitly fitted the pipeline itself nor the fitted `RandomizedSearchCV` returns the fitted base estimator (despite calling `.fit()`  on it while running the search) with the exception of the `best_estimator_` in the case described above.

Here's an example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, train_test_split

iris = load_iris(as_frame=True)
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

steps = [
     ("rfe", RFE(estimator = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 42))),
     ("est", RandomForestClassifier())
]
rf_clf_pl = Pipeline(steps = steps)

params = {
    "rfe__n_features_to_select" : range(2, X_train.shape[1] + 1),
    "est__random_state" : np.linspace(0, 42, 5).astype(int),
    "est__n_estimators" : range(50, 201, 10),
    "est__max_depth" : [None] + list(range(5, 16, 3)),
    "est__max_leaf_nodes" : [None] + list(range(100, 201, 20))
}

rs = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf_clf_pl, cv = 4, param_distributions = params, n_jobs = -1, n_iter = 100, random_state = 42)

rs.fit(X_train, y_train)

rs.best_estimator_.named_steps['rfe'].support_
```

Eventually, if you want to access the explicit names of the retained features, you can retrieve them via `rs.feature_names_in_[np.where(rs.best_estimator_.named_steps['rfe'].support_)[0]]`.